# Create a decimal to binary converter using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am looking to create a program that will convert an integer to a binary and the other way around, but I do not exactly know how to do it or how to approach this problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
#Method that check if string is a number.
def is_number?(string)
  true if Float(string) rescue false
end

#Method to convert decimal to binary
def decimal_to_binary(number)
  if is_number?(number)==false
    return "This method only accepts positive integers."
  elsif number<=0
    return "This method only accepts positive integers."
  else
    return #HERE it needs to converts decimal to binary
  end
end

#Method to convert binary to decimal
def binary_to_decimal(number)
end
```

Here is a little explanation of what a binary is in case you do not know/remember:

You count 0, 1, then you have to start over at zero and add a column! The next column is worth twice the value of the first column. Since binary is a base 2 system, each digit represents a power of 2, with the rightmost digit representing 20 (0), the next representing 21 (2), then 22 (4), 23 (8) and so on.

Comment: Provide a test case, i.e, an example of input and expected result.

Comment: I believe the lack of interest in your question is due to the fact that a float does not have a binary representation; it is generally represented by its sign, mantissa and exponent. The latter two are non-negative integers, which of course have binary representations. (The exponent is normally added to another value (e.g., 127) in order to represent both positive and negative exponents. Similarly, a binary number has an integer representation, but no binary number is the same as a float that has a fractional part. See, e.g., [this](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Float, as ruby does it, doesn't have a binary representation. If you want to convert between bases you can use to_s by passing the base in as a paramter.

```
21.to_s(2) #-> 10101
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could do this but the other way around (from binary to base 10). Is it 1010.to_s(10)?

Comment: Yup! You can write binary in ruby by prefixing it with `0b`. So do `0b10101.to_s(10)` if you want to convert 21 in binary back to decimal.

Comment: `num.to_s` defaults to decimal. So `0b10101.to_s` works just like `0b10101.to_s(10)`

Comment: @Pabi you can also use `String#to_i(base)` to convert back. E.g. `21.to_s(2) # => "10101"`, `"10101".to_i(2) # => 21`